# combine of 2 pine script Shadowing variable issue

Tags: pine-script, compiler-warnings

I'm writing a strategy using `Pine-script`, my first experience writing code.
Here, I want to combine 2 `Pine-script`. but here some yellow warnings come and stop it.

> Warning at 410:13 Shadowing variable 'a' which exists in parent scope.
> Did you want to use the ':=' operator instead of '='?
>
> Warning at 420:9 Shadowing variable 'l' which exists in parent scope.
> Did you want to use the ':=' operator instead of '=' ?

I am trying to use this `Pine-Script` code

```
length = input.int(50, 'Evaluation Window', minval=0, maxval=200)
fcast = input.int(50, 'Forecast Window', minval=1, maxval=200)

fmode = input.string('Similarity', 'Forecast Mode', options=['Similarity', 'Dissimilarity'])
cmode = input.string('Cumulative', 'Forecast Construction', options=['Cumulative', 'Mean', 'Linreg'])
src = input(close)

fcast_col = input.color(#2157f3, 'Forecast Style', inline='fcast_style', group='Style')
fcast_style = input.string('· · ·', '', options=['──', '- - -', '· · ·'], inline='fcast_style', group='Style')

show_area = input.bool(true, 'Show Area', inline='areas', group='Style')
fcast_area = input.color(color.new(#ff5d00, 50), '', inline='areas', group='Style')
corr_area = input.color(color.new(#0cb51a, 50), '', inline='areas', group='Style')
eval_area = input.color(color.new(color.gray, 50), '', inline='areas', group='Style')
//----
var lines = array.new_line(0)
if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to fcast - 1 by 1
        array.push(lines, line.new(na, na, na, na))
//----
n = bar_index
d = ta.change(src)

top = ta.highest(src, length + fcast * 2)
btm = ta.lowest(src, length + fcast * 2)

if barstate.islast
    float val = na
    k = 0
    A = array.new_float(0)
    X = array.new_int(0)
    for i = 0 to fcast * 2 + length by 1
        array.push(A, src[i])
        if cmode == 'Linreg'
            array.push(X, n[i])

    a = array.slice(A, 0, fcast - 1)
    for i = 0 to length - 1 by 1
        b = array.slice(A, fcast + i, fcast * 2 + i - 1)
        r = array.covariance(a, b) / (array.stdev(a) * array.stdev(b))
        if fmode == 'Similarity'
            val := r >= nz(val, r) ? r : val
            val
        else
            val := r <= nz(val, r) ? r : val
            val
        k := val == r ? i : k
        k

    prev = src
    current = src

    for i = 0 to fcast - 1 by 1
        e = d[fcast + k + fcast - i - 1]
        if cmode == 'Mean'
            current := array.avg(a) + e
            current
        else if cmode == 'Linreg'
            a = array.slice(A, 0, fcast)
            x = array.slice(X, 0, fcast)
            alpha = array.covariance(a, x) / array.variance(x)
            beta = array.avg(a) - alpha * array.avg(x)
            current := alpha * (n + i + 1) + beta + e
            current
        else
            current += e
            current

        l = array.get(lines, i)
        line.set_xy1(l, n + i, prev)
        line.set_xy2(l, n + i + 1, current)
        line.set_color(l, fcast_col)

        if fcast_style == '- - -'
            line.set_style(l, line.style_dashed)
        else if fcast_style == '· · ·'
            line.set_style(l, line.style_dotted)

        prev := current
        prev

    if show_area
        box.delete(box.new(n - length - fcast * 2 + 1, top, n - fcast + 1, btm, border_color=na, bgcolor=eval_area)[1])
        box.delete(box.new(n - fcast + 1, top, n, btm, border_color=na, bgcolor=fcast_area)[1])
        box.delete(box.new(n - k - fcast * 2 + 1, btm, n - k - fcast, top, border_color=na, bgcolor=corr_area)[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `a` is first declared in the scope of `if barstate.islast`.

```
if barstate.islast
    ...
    a = array.slice(A, 0, fcast - 1)
```

Then further below it is declared again in a nested scope two levels deeper:

```
if barstate.islast
    ...
    a = array.slice(A, 0, fcast - 1)
    ...
    for i = 0 to fcast - 1 by 1
    ...
        if cmode == 'Mean'
        ... 
        else if cmode == 'Linreg'
            a = array.slice(A, 0, fcast)
            ...
```

So, the `a` within `else if cmode == 'Linreg'` is a new independent variable, shadowing the `a` declared above, i.e. the value of `a` within that scope (`else if`) is independent from the value of `a` from outside that scope. If you meant that to be the same variable as in the parent scope you could use `:=` instead of `=` to tell the compiler that this is an already existing variable `a`, and no need to create a new one.

You can just rename the second one to, e.g. `a1` within that section of code  and the error will go:

```
        else if cmode == 'Linreg'
            a1 = array.slice(A, 0, fcast)
            x = array.slice(X, 0, fcast)
            alpha = array.covariance(a1, x) / array.variance(x)
            beta = array.avg(a1) - alpha * array.avg(x)
            current := alpha * (n + i + 1) + beta + e
            current
```

This way, no warning and the forecast line is showing:

```
// The script is based on "The Echo Forecast" by LuxAlgo
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

length = input.int(50, 'Evaluation Window', minval=0, maxval=200)
fcast = input.int(50, 'Forecast Window', minval=1, maxval=200)

fmode = input.string('Similarity', 'Forecast Mode', options=['Similarity', 'Dissimilarity'])
cmode = input.string('Cumulative', 'Forecast Construction', options=['Cumulative', 'Mean', 'Linreg'])
src = input(close)

fcast_col = input.color(#2157f3, 'Forecast Style', inline='fcast_style', group='Style')
fcast_style = input.string('· · ·', '', options=['──', '- - -', '· · ·'], inline='fcast_style', group='Style')

show_area = input.bool(true, 'Show Area', inline='areas', group='Style')
fcast_area = input.color(color.new(#ff5d00, 50), '', inline='areas', group='Style')
corr_area = input.color(color.new(#0cb51a, 50), '', inline='areas', group='Style')
eval_area = input.color(color.new(color.gray, 50), '', inline='areas', group='Style')
//----
var lines = array.new_line(0)
if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to fcast - 1 by 1
        array.push(lines, line.new(na, na, na, na))
//----
n = bar_index
d = ta.change(src)

top = ta.highest(src, length + fcast * 2)
btm = ta.lowest(src, length + fcast * 2)

if barstate.islast
    float val = na
    k = 0
    A = array.new_float(0)
    X = array.new_int(0)
    for i = 0 to fcast * 2 + length by 1
        array.push(A, src[i])
        if cmode == 'Linreg'
            array.push(X, n[i])

    a = array.slice(A, 0, fcast - 1)
    for i = 0 to length - 1 by 1
        b = array.slice(A, fcast + i, fcast * 2 + i - 1)
        r = array.covariance(a, b) / (array.stdev(a) * array.stdev(b))
        if fmode == 'Similarity'
            val := r >= nz(val, r) ? r : val
            val
        else
            val := r <= nz(val, r) ? r : val
            val
        k := val == r ? i : k
        k

    prev = src
    current = src

    for i = 0 to fcast - 1 by 1
        e = d[fcast + k + fcast - i - 1]
        if cmode == 'Mean'
            current := array.avg(a) + e
            current
        else if cmode == 'Linreg'
            a1 = array.slice(A, 0, fcast)
            x = array.slice(X, 0, fcast)
            alpha = array.covariance(a1, x) / array.variance(x)
            beta = array.avg(a1) - alpha * array.avg(x)
            current := alpha * (n + i + 1) + beta + e
            current
        else
            current += e
            current

        l = array.get(lines, i)
        line.set_xy1(l, n + i, prev)
        line.set_xy2(l, n + i + 1, current)
        line.set_color(l, fcast_col)

        if fcast_style == '- - -'
            line.set_style(l, line.style_dashed)
        else if fcast_style == '· · ·'
            line.set_style(l, line.style_dotted)

        prev := current
        prev

    if show_area
        box.delete(box.new(n - length - fcast * 2 + 1, top, n - fcast + 1, btm, border_color=na, bgcolor=eval_area)[1])
        box.delete(box.new(n - fcast + 1, top, n, btm, border_color=na, bgcolor=fcast_area)[1])
        box.delete(box.new(n - k - fcast * 2 + 1, btm, n - k - fcast, top, border_color=na, bgcolor=corr_area)[1])
```

Comment: ya its work but now l warning still showing. and also prediction the line not showing

Comment: i fix the l issue by changing  l  to l1 and l warning noe but the prediction line not showing like this https://i.gyazo.com/b3a25593f10c65580fdb0950e538b617.png                                                                                                 l1 = array.get(lines, i)
        line.set_xy1(l1, n + i, prev)
        line.set_xy2(l1, n + i + 1, current)
        line.set_color(l1, fcast_col)

        if fcast_style == '- - -'
            line.set_style(l1, line.style_dashed)
        else if fcast_style == '· · ·'
            line.set_style(l1, line.style_dotted)

Comment: Please see the edits. 
I added a mention of LuxAlgo, since the script almost entirely repeats his The ECHO Forecast: https://www.tradingview.com/script/Y8v4W3mX-The-Echo-Forecast-LuxAlgo/

Comment: thanks for this i mix up ut bot and lux.  but here i have one last question. i wanna hide default candel pattern via indicator code. what will be the code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but maybe this guide on plotting your own candles can help: https://youtu.be/znUjP2bT_Qk

Comment: i mean when you open any chart that time default candle pattern will show. i just want to disable the default pattern by pine code, as i want to show my custom candle only

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to hide/disable or change type of chart candles, there is only a way to change their color or draw new candles. Would be interested to learn if I am wrong.